# Is there any difference if I swipe an app off the screen or I press the 'x' button?

Tags: apps

When I long press the '<-' button and I see all the running apps, I can close them using two ways:

- swipe them off the bottom of the screen
- press the 'x' button.

A friend of mine told me that it's preferable to press the 'x' button rather than to swipe them, but he didn't say why.

Is there any difference in those two way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference between closing an app using the X button and swiping it down, they do the exact same thing.

Although note that swiping apps down is only available since Windows Phone 8.1. In WP 8.0 the only option is the X button, added with Update 3 (before that, there was no way at all to close apps from the switcher).

For more information on using the app switcher, see [the official how-to](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/how-to/wp8/basics/switch-between-apps).